# node-rdkafka - debug set to all but I only see broker transport failure

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am trying to connect to kafka server. Authentication is based on GSSAPI.

```sh
/opt/app-root/src/server/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/error.js:411
  return new LibrdKafkaError(e);
         ^
Error: broker transport failure
    at Function.createLibrdkafkaError (/opt/app-root/src/server/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/error.js:411:10)
    at /opt/app-root/src/server/node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/client.js:350:28
```

This my test_kafka.js:

```js
const Kafka = require('node-rdkafka');

const kafkaConf = {
  'group.id': 'espdev2',
  'enable.auto.commit': true,
  'metadata.broker.list': 'br01',
  'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
  'sasl.kerberos.service.name': 'kafka',
  'sasl.kerberos.keytab': 'svc_esp_kafka_nonprod.keytab',
  'sasl.kerberos.principal': 'svc_esp_kafka_nonprod@INT.LOCAL',
  'debug': 'all',
  'enable.ssl.certificate.verification': true,
  //'ssl.certificate.location': 'some-root-ca.cer',
  'ssl.ca.location': 'some-root-ca.cer',
  //'ssl.key.location': 'svc_esp_kafka_nonprod.keytab',
};

const topics = 'hello1';

console.log(Kafka.features);

let readStream = new Kafka.KafkaConsumer.createReadStream(kafkaConf, { "auto.offset.reset": "earliest" }, { topics })
readStream.on('data', function (message) {
  const messageString = message.value.toString();
  console.log(`Consumed message on Stream: ${messageString}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this issue for the explanation of this error:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1987

Taken from @edenhill:

> As a general rule for librdkafka-based clients: given that the cluster and client are correctly configured, all errors can be ignored as they are most likely temporary and librdkafka will attempt to recover automatically. 
> In this specific case; if a group coordinator request fails it will be retried (using any broker in state Up) within 500ms. The current assignment and group membership will not be affected, if a new coordinator is found before the missing heartbeats times out the membership (session.timeout.ms).
> Auto offset commits will be stalled until a new coordinator is found. 
> In a future version we'll extend the error type to include a severity, allowing applications to happily ignore non-terminal errors. At this time an application should consider all errors informational, and not terminal.